# In Python Calculate the Total Federal Tax

Tags: python

I am writing a program where it calculates the salary, federal tax, and sales tax, and then it puts them into categories based on salary. After, it is supposed to calculate the total of all the federal taxes for each person, but my program just adds the latest federal tax calculation. Not all the federal taxes per salary. I just need help in figuring out how to calculate the total for the federal taxes.
Here's my code:

```
response = "yes"
over100 = 0
btwn50to100 = 0
btwn25to50 = 0
below25 = 0
while(response=="yes") or (response=="YES"):
    salary = input("Please one persons salary: ")
    if(salary>=100000):
        over100 = over100 + 1
        FederalTax = 0.20
    elif(salary>=50000) and (salary<100000):
        btwn50to100 = btwn50to100 + 1
        FederalTax = 0.15
    elif(salary>=25000) and (salary<50000):
        btwn25to50 = btwn25to50 + 1
        FederalTax = 0.15
    elif(salary<25000):
        below25 = below25 + 1
        FederalTax = 0.15
    StateTax = 0.05
    FederalTax = int(float(salary * FederalTax))
    StateTax = int(float(salary * StateTax))
    NetSalary = int(float(salary - FederalTax - StateTax))
    totalfederaltax = int(float(FederalTax + FederalTax))  #This is where I messed up
    print("Your federal tax is :" +str(FederalTax))
    print("Your state tax is :" +str(StateTax))
    print("Your net salary is: " +str(NetSalary))
    response = input("Would you like to continue?(yes/no): ")
print("*****")
print("The number of pepole who earned more than 100000 is: " +str(over100))
print("The number of pepole who earned More than or equal to 50000 and less than 100000 is: " +str(btwn50to100))
print("The number of pepole who earned More than or equal to 25000 and less than 50000 is: " +str(btwn25to50))
print("The number of pepole who earned Below 25000 is: " +str(below25))
print("The total federa tax is: " +str(totalfederaltax))
```

Comment: `FederalTax + FederalTax` is just `2 * FederalTax`

Comment: @MichaelButscher Yea I figured that lol, but do you know how to calculate all the federal taxes?

Comment: Can you give a mathematical expression of the expected result?

Comment: totalFederalTax = FederalTax ?

Comment: I think you messed up because you're overwriting this value `FederalTax = int(float(salary * FederalTax))`

Comment: I recommend you use functions `calc_tax(salary)` that gives you a smaller sub problem to solve that may be more manageable

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's an interesting program.

```
response = "yes"
over100 = 0
btwn50to100 = 0
btwn25to50 = 0
below25 = 0
total_federal_tax = 0

while response.lower() == "yes":
    salary = int(input("Please one persons salary: "))
    if(salary >= 100000):
        over100 = over100 + 1
        FederalTax = 0.20
    elif(salary >= 50000) and (salary < 100000):
        btwn50to100 = btwn50to100 + 1
        FederalTax = 0.15
    elif(salary >= 25000) and (salary < 50000):
        btwn25to50 = btwn25to50 + 1
        FederalTax = 0.15
    elif(salary < 25000):
        below25 = below25 + 1
        FederalTax = 0.15

    StateTax = 0.05
    FederalTax = int(float(salary * FederalTax))
    StateTax = int(float(salary * StateTax))
    NetSalary = int(float(salary - FederalTax - StateTax))
    total_federal_tax += FederalTax
    print("Your federal tax is :" +str(FederalTax))
    print("Your state tax is :" +str(StateTax))
    print("Your net salary is: " +str(NetSalary))
    response = input("Would you like to continue?(yes/no): ")

print("*****")
print("The number of pepole who earned more than 100000 is: " +str(over100))
print("The number of pepole who earned More than or equal to 50000 and less than 100000 is: " +str(btwn50to100))
print("The number of pepole who earned More than or equal to 25000 and less than 50000 is: " +str(btwn25to50))
print("The number of pepole who earned Below 25000 is: " + str(below25))
print("The total federa tax is: " + str(total_federal_tax))
```

Answer (score 0):

> Not all the federal taxes per salary.

IIUC, you need to start with a variable outside the loop, then add within the loop if you're looking to add up total tax paid for all inputs

```
total_federal_tax = 0
while response.lower() =="yes":
    salary = int(input("Please one persons salary: ")) 
    # TODO: compute federal_tax
    total_federal_tax += salary * federal_tax
print(total_federal_tax)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import math


class Counter(object): # mutable object is needed to acces it from tuple
    def __init__(self, start_value=0):
        self.value = start_value

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)


response = "yes"
over100 = Counter()
btwn50to100 = Counter()
btwn25to50 = Counter()
below25 = Counter()
totalFederalTax = 0

STATE_TAX_RATE = 0.05

TAX_MAP = {(0, 25000): (0.15, below25),
           (25000, 50000): (0.15, btwn25to50),
           (50000, 100000): (0.15, btwn50to100),
           (100000, math.inf): (0.20, over100)}


def calc_federal_tax(salary):
    for compartments, values in TAX_MAP.items():
        if compartments[0] <= salary < compartments[1]:
            values[1].value += 1
            return values[0]



while response.lower() == "yes":
    salary = input("Please one persons salary: ")
    federalTaxRate = calc_federal_tax(salary)

    federalTax = int(salary * federalTaxRate)
    stateTax  = int(salary * STATE_TAX_RATE)
    netSalary = int(salary - federalTax - stateTax)
    totalFederalTax += federalTax
    print("Your federal tax is :" + str(federalTax))
    print("Your state tax is :" + str(stateTax))
    print("Your net salary is: " + str(netSalary))
    response = input("Would you like to continue?(yes/no): ")
print("*****")
print("The number of pepole who earned more than 100000 is: " + str(over100))
print("The number of pepole who earned More than or equal to 50000 and less than 100000 is: " + str(btwn50to100))
print("The number of pepole who earned More than or equal to 25000 and less than 50000 is: " + str(btwn25to50))
print("The number of pepole who earned Below 25000 is: " + str(below25))
print("The total federal tax is: " + str(totalFederalTax))
```